# What is the croupier saying during this game of baccarat

Tags: dialogue, james-bond, translation, for-your-eyes-only

What is the croupier saying during this game of baccarat from the James Bond film *For Your Eyes Only*? The subtitles only say "speaking French" and I know that much, but would actually like to understand the dialogue.

From the start until 2:13.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No translation is given, I think, because it is not necessary to follow what is going on: Bond wins. If you understand Baccarat, you will follow the game. But let's see where my rusty French will go.
Let's use the following notation:

- **(time)  English (French):**
- (0:07) 500,000 from Banker (Cinq cent mille le Banco)
- (0:08)  Who will match? (Qui fait Banco? (I think))
- (0:12)  Banker, cards if you please. (Banco, cartes s'il vous plait.)
- (0:24)  8 (huit)
- (0:27)  And 9 from Banker (et neuf la Banque?) [Even though Bond shows five = error in editing the film]
- (0:40)  1 million from Banker, sir (Un million a Banco, monsieur)
- (0:42)  Who matches Banker? (Qui fait Banco?)
- (0:58)  1 million (un million)
- (1:02)  Banker follows (Banco suivi)
- (1:04)  Cards, if you please (Cartes s'il vous plait)
- (1:14)  Card [hit me] (Carte)
- (1:32)  Nine to Banker (Neuf la Banque)
- (1:36)  I pass. (Je m'en passe.)